# Get status for a PUT request on Jersey client

Tags: java, web-services, jersey

I have a webservice defined with Jersey in the server side like this:

```
@POST
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
@Path("/foo")
public Response bar(List<Foo> listFoo) {    
 try {
        //save the resource
        } catch (Exception e) {
        log.error("Error saving", e);
        return Response.status(Status.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR).build();
    }
    return Response.status(Status.OK).build();
}
```

I am trying to get the server status in my Jersey client like this:

```
Response response = ws.type(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML).post(Response.class,list);
```

But I get the error:

```
A message body reader for Java class javax.ws.rs.core.Response, and Java type class javax.ws.rs.core.Response, and MIME media type application/xml was not found javax.ws.rs.core.Response
```

I don't really need the Response object, just the status code, how could I get it?

Comment: what does it `@Produce`?

Comment: a javax.rs.core.Response

Comment: Ah, ok, sorry! MediaType.APPLICATION_XML

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, I solved it by changing the request response type:

```
Response response = ws.type(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML).post(Response.class,list);
```

with

```
ClientResponse response = ws.type(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML).post(ClientResponse.class,list);
```

being `ClientResponse` a `com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientResponse`

Answer (score 1):

Add `@Consumes` annotation to your web-serivce and the parameter to your `bar()` method, because you are trying to put there some object named `list`.

And I would recommend you to use `@POST` instead, because canonical `@PUT` does not return a response.

UPD. By the way, you have your entity empty - you should better remove your `@Produces` annotation and just return `Response` with its status set.

UPD2. and remove `.accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)` method from client side.

Comment: Thanks, tested, but I've got the same results. The list is arriving good, if I return an "OK" String instead of Response, works fine. I'll update the question.

Comment: I am getting it on the client side. If I debug on the server side, I see that the process receives the call and executes just fine, sending a Status.OK Response.

Comment: Changes done, now the message changes to: A message body reader for Java class javax.ws.rs.core.Response, and Java type class javax.ws.rs.core.Response, and MIME media type application/octet-stream was not found